# Why do my material design components not register the appropriate color, as stated on the material.io website?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, material-components, material-components-android

I have just started learning about material design on the official material.io website and I have decided to try it out in a new project. I made a basic project with an empty activity, added a layout and added two components:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.authentication.LoginActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RRRRRRRRR"/>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TTTTTTTT"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Nothing too fancy. My problem is that the code above does not reflect the colors I have defined and implemented in my theme and I can't seem to figure out why (I've spent hours trying to find the right answer on the internet, as well as the official documentation of material.io and still nothing). These are my styles and colors xml files:
Colors

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#880e4f</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryVariantLight">#bc477b</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryVariantDark">#560027</color>
    <color name="colorSecondary">#006064</color>
    <color name="colorSecondaryVariantLight">#428e92</color>
    <color name="colorSecondaryVariantDark">#00363a</color>
    <color name="colorOnPrimary">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="colorOnSecondary">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="colorError">#B00020</color>
    <color name="colorOnError">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="colorSurface">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="colorOnSurface">#212121</color>
    <color name="colorBackground">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="colorOnBackground">#212121</color>
</resources>
```

Styles

```
<resources>
    <style name="MaterialTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryVariantDark</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/colorOnPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/colorSecondaryVariantDark</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/colorOnSecondary</item>
        <item name="colorError">@color/colorError</item>
        <item name="colorOnError">@color/colorOnError</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/colorSurface</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/colorOnSurface</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>
        <item name="colorOnBackground">@color/colorOnBackground</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I'm almost 100% sure I'm just missing something in my knowledge but I can't seem to find the answer to the problem. I highly appreciate all help you can provide me with. Thanks in advance.

The following is the screen of my layout and the preview (which is completely white).
[image]

Comment: Just post a screen and tell us which colors are wrong.

Comment: Did u inherit `AppCompatActivity`? And maybe it's a banal question: which Android version do u use for testing?

Comment: The texts in both edittext and textview are colored white when in my styles it's said that both OnBackground and OnSurface are a variant of black.

The colouring is wrong in the preview screen, which was automatically set to use the best one. I should have stated that earlier, sorry.

Comment: Could you specify the versions of the Material Components for Android library and/or other relevant libraries you're using?

Comment: @Шах I don't think I inherited it since I haven't found that to be necessary on the material.io website (nowhere was it stated that it was needed, I assumed it was built into the MaterialComponents theme)

Comment: @Edric I've just created the project with the latest dependencies, therefore I'm using the following:

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01'

Comment: @LeoLyo visit [Android Developers resource](http://developers.android.com) to learn how to implement Material design.

Comment: @LeoLyo you need to add appcompat and design libraries and inherit your activity from `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: @Шах I did try to learn how to implement material design into the application but I was not able to find the exact connection between let's say their Variant colors and Android's colors (there are no Variant colors in Android, it doesn't recognize them as a standard). Nonetheless I thank you for trying to solve my absurd question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<style name="MaterialTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
    <!-- Used by TextView -->
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/...</item>

    <!-- Used by TextInputLayout -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```

[image]
[image]